# Xamarin.iOS C# interoperability with objective-c: callbacks from objective-c to non-static C# methods

Tags: objective-c, callback, xamarin.ios, language-interoperability

I'm an objective-c novice, so please forgive what may be incorrect terminology.

In Xamarin.iOS, I am successfully employing a C# class with multiple static methods to implement callback functionality from objective-C to C#.  I'd like to avoid the creation of a binding library (don't want to use Sharpie and related tools / steps).  I'm looking for a way for objective-c to callback to non-static methods in C#.   Is it possible for objective-c to callback to non-static Xamarin.iOS C# methods? My objective-c to C# call-back technique is as follows and is further described below:

- Create a class in C# that contains my static call-back methods.  This class inherits from NSObject.
- Create a @protocol in objective-c that matches the "call-back" class defined in C#.
- Instantiate the "call-back" class in C# and get its NSObject.Class.Handle
- Pass the NSObject.Class.Handle for the "call-back" class instance from C# to objective-c,
- In objective-c, cast the handle to an id (for the previously defined @protocol) and use this id as a delegate to the C# class instance (which now appears as an @interface instance in objective-c).

Using this technique, I am able to treat my C# "call-back" class instance as an @interface instance in objective-c.  In objective-c, I can call methods in my C# class instance by treating them as @interface instance methods.

**In C#**

- Define a class that inherits from NSObject (NSObject includes Class.Handle definition)
- [Register] the class and [Export] the static callbacks within the class
- Use 'NSObject.Class.Handle' to get IntPtr class handle
- Marshal the class instance handle (IntPtr) to objective-c as 'UnmanagedType.IUnknown'

**In objective-c**

- define a '@protocol' that corresponds to the C# class. The @protocol has instance methods that correspond to each static callback method in the C# class
- cast the IntPtr (from C#) as an 'id' for the '@protocol'
- use the id as a delegate to the C# class instance (which behaves as an objective-c @interface instance)

Using this technique, I can use the C# class handle as a protocol id in objective-c and reference the C# class as an @interface in objective-c.

Can this same (or similar) method (passing a class handle from C# to objective-c and using this class handle as the delegate) be employed to call non-static C# methods from objective-c?

```
    // C# "call-back" class
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : NSObject
    {
        [Export("OnLoginSucceeded:")]
        public static void OnLoginSucceeded(string sessionToken)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        [Export("OnRequestFailed")]
        public static void OnRequestFailed()
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        [Export("OnConnectionFailed")]
        public static void OnConnectionFailed()
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        public IntPtr GetInstancePointer()
        {
            IntPtr self = Class.Handle;
            return self;
        }
    }


    // objective-c protocol for C# "call-back" class
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @protocol AppDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)OnLoginSucceeded : (NSString*)sessionToken;
    - (void)OnRequestFailed;
    - (void)OnConnectionFailed;

    @end


    // objective-c calls to C# callback
    [self.appDelegate OnLoginSucceeded : response.sessionToken];
    [self.appDelegate OnRequestFailed];
    [self.appDelegate OnConnectionFailed];
```

Comment: If answer be helpful , remember to mark ot vote up later when have time.Thanks in advance *.^

Comment: Your article is very informative.  Thank you.  I'm not ready to mark it as "the answer" to my question, but it contains more information than I've found anywhere else about C# / objective-c bindings.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for objective-c to callback to non-static Xamarin.iOS C# methods?

Not too much understanding **non-static** , howver I know that when [binding custom controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=macos#caveats-of-binding-custom-controls) , **Binding properties must be static** .

- **Binding properties must be static** - When defining the binding of properties, the `[Static]` attribute must be used.

Comment: The link you provided defines an interface in C# and then states that [Static] is required "because the contract is part of an interface, and interfaces have no notion of static vs instance declarations..."   My technique employs a class definition (derived from NSObject) in C# that is paired with a @protocol definition in objective-C.  I have not found my tecnique documented anywhere which is why I'm asking my question.

Comment: @Tony Okey , got it . If good points about your tecnique will share here later .